# Fermi sphere of correlated systems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

I am studying [this](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642045172) book (Fundamentals of Physics of solids: Vol 3). On page 14 there is a calculation regarding change of fermi surfaces due to correlation of electrons. To illustrate that a discontinuity remains in the momentum distribution function they are calculating momentum distribution. The average number of electrons in correlated ground state $|\psi>$ with momentum $k$ and spin $\sigma$ is given as (equ. 28.2.1):
$$<n_{k\sigma}>=<\psi|c_{k\sigma}^\dagger c_{k\sigma}|\psi>$$
where ground state $|\psi>$ can be written as (equ 28.2.2):
$$|\psi>=|\psi_{FS}>+\frac{U}{V} \sum_{k_1,k_2,q}\frac{1}{\epsilon_{k_1}+\epsilon_{k_2}-\epsilon_{k_1+q}-\epsilon_{k_2-q}}c_{k_1+q\uparrow}c_{k_2-q\downarrow}c_{k_2\downarrow}c_{k_1\uparrow}|\psi_{FS}>$$
where $|\psi_{FS}>$ is ground state of uncorrelated system and other term is perturbation due to correlation. Correlation can be taken as two particles with wave vectors $k_1$ and $k_2$ are scattered into states with wave vectors $k_1+q $ and $k_2-q$. So far I am understanding what's happening.

After that in next paragraph they are discussing the case $|k|>k_F$. For non-vanishing perturbative momentum distribution $k$ should be either equal to (depending on the spin) $k_1+q$ or $k_2-q$. **My first question is why?** Going on, there is this sentence that is confusing me:

> "The conditions that $k_1$ and $k_2$ are inside the Fermi sphere, while $k_1+k_2-k$ are outside, can be expressed by the fermi distribution function."

**My second question is what is meaning of these conditions and why are we taking these conditions?**
Then they calculated average number of electrons in state $|\psi>$ that is:
$$<n_{k\sigma}>_{|k|>k_F}=\frac{U^2}{V^2} \sum_{k_1,k_2}\frac{[1-f_0(\epsilon_{k_1+k_2-k})]f_0(\epsilon_{k_1})f_0(\epsilon_{k_2})}{(\epsilon_{k_1}+\epsilon_{k_2}-\epsilon_{k}-\epsilon_{k_1+k_2-k})^2}$$
**My third question is how they got this equation?**

On the next page #15 they is a diagram (fig. 28.2) in which they are trying to give some explanation regarding allowed values of $k_2$ but my dumb brain is not able to understand it. NEED HELP.

I am posting pictures of relevant two pages here:
[image]
[image]